# Android - Notification intent not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I hace a BroadCast receiver I use to send a notification. Well, the problem is that I tried all the solutions related to this subject in stackoverflow with no success: I can't see anything after clicking on the notification.
Here is my code:

```
private void sendFinishNotification(Context context, String user_parent){
    try {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Sending Notification");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, RatingActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_bs)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.bs_finished))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.come_rate_bs))
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notif);
        Log.e("CheckingService", "Building Notification");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I tried not using TaskStackBuilder and just getting the pending intent with getActivity() (as well as getBroadcast()) with no success.

Maybe there is a problem with the context? I tried using context.getApplicationContext() instead of context, anything changed.

Comment: Is `RatingActivity` in your manifest?

Comment: Do you see any error mesages in the logcat when you cklick on the `Notification`? Don't filter the logcat as you might miss something important!